# Why don’t make check the timestamp when the dependency file is not generated?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, make, makefile

I create an ugly Makefile, it worked beyond my expectations. When main.o is not built successfully, the executable is built every time I make. In my opinion, after the main.o target command is executed, make will compare the timestamp of the main.o file with the main file. There is no main.o file at this time, so the main file should be the latest. Why is the command of the main target executed. In my case main is always present after the first build and it is rebuilt each time make is executed, Although the content is the same.

When I add a main.o file that is older than main by shell, I change the main.c file and use the make command to update only main1.o, but not main, indicating that make compares main and main.o timestamp.

Is there a problem with my understanding? Is it my misunderstanding of the execution process of make.

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o main1 main1.o
    echo generate

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main1.o
```

I don't have enough reputation so I've inserted an image link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAX6j.png

Comment: The target in the Makefile is `main` but the rule builds `main1`. The image is different from your text but it has the target `main.o` and the rule builds `main1.o`. I don't see how you can ever get a clean build with this Makefile.

Comment: I've read through your text three times, but I cannot make sense of it. Try to restructure your thoughts and restructure the text accordingly. Also: do not add pictures of text but add the text to the question. Inserting a picture of text is actually bad for your reputation, so the  remark that you added a picture because you don't have enough reputation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a probleem with the Makefile

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o main1 main1.o
    echo generate

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main1.o
```

There are a number of issues with this Makefile, most of them created by the confusion between `main` and `main1`.

When you type `make`, it will try to create the target `main`. Main depends on `main.o`, so `make` will try to create `main.o`. There is a rule for that in the Makefile, so `make` will use that and execute

```
gcc -c main.c -o main1.o
```

Note that this creates `main1.o` and not `main.o`. After the execution of this rule, there is still no `main.o`.

`make` doesn't care about that and will execute the rules to create `main`:

```
gcc -o main1 main1.o
```

This will create the executable `main1`, not `mai` that was the original target. However, `main1` will be there.

The next time you run `make`, make will go through the same procedure. It will try to create the target `main`, because main is not there. `main1` is there, but that is not the target that `make` wants to create.

`main` depends on `main.o`. There is no `main.o`, so `make` will try to create it. There is a `main1.o`, but `main` does not depend on that.  As we've seen, there is a rule for `main.o` that is then executed.

and so on.

A correct version would be:

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o main main.o
    echo generate

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
```